# Change word output format in Rmarkdown by pdf format

Tags: r, pdf, ms-word, knitr, r-markdown

Is there any possibility of changing the input and output formats of the console in word?

The output format in PDF differs between an input and output of the console
[image: The output format in PDF differs between an input and output of the console]

The output format in word has the same format for both input and output.
[image: The output format in word has the same format for both input and output.]

I tried to use the template option for word but I do not see the way to solve it.

Comment: "Template option" for Word? I think you may be assuming the entire world is using your particular IDE. Your 2 png files look pretty much the same and certainly do not illustrate a problem that I can detect.

Answer (score 0):

One option to not exactly meet your requirement, but one step below

From the output options (next to Knit Word Button, when you click on the dropdown), select syntax highlighting to monochrome.

This will enable your output to all be in one format. Next choose your code blocks and highlight them the usual way you do in word